# How to authenticate a java application for the Google Contacts API?

Tags: java, google-oauth, gdata, google-contacts-api

I've had a java application running for a few years that synced some contacts from some database into the gmail account of a customer.

This stopped working a few days ago, presumably because Google [stopped supporting](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) the simple username/password authentication.

First question: Am I correct in assuming that the only supported authentication now is OAuth2?

Assuming that is the case, I don't understand what kind of authorization scheme/flow I should use. I can't show a dialog - this is a service type kind of application, and it should only access one specific customer account that I control. I think I should use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), but the documentation says this:

> Typically, an application uses a service account when the application
>   uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.

But I want to use user data - the Contacts, specifically.

For that scenario the documentation has this to say:

> If you have a Google Apps domain—if you use Google Apps for Work, for
>   example—an administrator of the Google Apps domain can authorize an
>   application to access user data on behalf of users in the Google Apps
>   domain. For example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API
>   to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain
>   would use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on
>   behalf of users. Authorizing a service account to access data on
>   behalf of users in a domain is sometimes referred to as "delegating
>   domain-wide authority" to a service account.

But, I don't have a Google Apps domain.

So... now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question: Am I correct in assuming that the only supported authentication now is OAuth2?**

Yes

**So... now what?**

The closest analogy to a username-password is a refresh token (which is simply a string). IE:-

- If your app has a refresh token, it can, at any time, access the resources granted to it
- Because of the power of a refresh token, it needs to be securely stored, just like a password

The steps required to get a refresh token are described here [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic)

That answer also contains a link which points to the Google docs for how to use a refresh token to obtain an access token.

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't know about refresh tokens. I will give it a shot tonight.

Answer (score 1):

And here some code (based on pinoyyid's suggestion):

```
String CLIENT_ID = "see instructions in accepted answer";
String CLIENT_SECRET = "see instructions in accepted answer";
String REFRESH_TOKEN = "see instructions in accepted answer";

Builder builder = new GoogleCredential.Builder();
builder.setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport());
builder.setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance());
builder.setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

Credential credential = builder.build();
credential.setRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN);
credential.refreshToken(); // gets the access token, using the refresh token

ContactsService contactsService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

Query query = new Query(new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"));
query.setMaxResults(10_000);

ContactFeed allContactsFeed = contactsService.getFeed(query, ContactFeed.class);

LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, allContactsFeed.getTitle().getPlainText());

for(ContactEntry contact : allContactsFeed.getEntries())
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: kudos for posting the code. One suggestion. There are circumstances in which the refresh token can be invalidated, therefore I would probably suggest storing it in a data file, rather than as a string literal.